# Common words in two different pandas data frame and colum

Tags: python, pandas

A

| x | disc |
| --- | --- |
| a | 'tall', 'short', 'medium' |
| b | 'small', 'long', 'short' |

B

| y |
| --- |
| 'tall', 'short' |
| 'short', 'long' |
| 'small', 'tall' |

output like-

| x | disc | tall short | short long |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 'tall', 'short', 'medium' | 1 | 0 |
| b | 'small', 'long', 'short' | 0 | 1 |

Answer (score 1):

Convert values to sets and find common words with set new columns:

```
for x in B['y']:
    s = set(x.split(', '))
    A[x] = [int(set(y.split(', ')) >= s) for y in A['disc']]
```

If necessarry remove only `0` columns add:

```
out = A.loc[:, A.ne(0).any()]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use set comparison with numpy broadcasting:

```
out = A.join(pd.DataFrame((A['disc'].apply(set).to_numpy()[:,None]
                           >= B['y'].apply(set).to_numpy()).astype(int),
                          columns=B['y'].apply(' '.join), index=A.index)
             )
```

Output:

```
   x                   disc  tall short  short long  small tall
0  a  [tall, short, medium]           1           0           0
1  b   [small, long, short]           0           1           0
```

If you want only the matches:

```
tmp = pd.DataFrame((A['disc'].apply(set).to_numpy()[:,None]
                     >= B['y'].apply(set).to_numpy()),
                    columns=B['y'].apply(' '.join), index=A.index)
                   
out = A.join(tmp.loc[:, tmp.any()].astype(int))
```

Output:

```
   x                   disc  tall short  short long
0  a  [tall, short, medium]           1           0
1  b   [small, long, short]           0           1
```

Comment: I see you unaccepted the answer, was there any issue?